# Exception when manually calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am attempting to manually call didSelectRowAtIndexPath on a UITableview. When doing so I get the following exception:

```
'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.
```

Here is the code causing the exception:

```
-(void)refreshLayerAtIndexPath:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:index];
    [self tableView:_tableViewLayers didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

I see nowhere to explicitly set the section.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: try [self tableView:_tableViewLayers didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row]; and see if that works

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` yourself. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Also, don't name your method `refreshLayerAtIndexPath:` since it doesn't take an index path, just an index.

Comment: @rmaddy or better yet, change the data type of the argument to `NSIndexPath *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With UITableView you also need to specify the section of NSIndexPath

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
```